# wp_dropdown_pages doesn't allow me to select more than one custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, dropdown

I am creating a "wine database",k to call it somehow.... Basically there is a custom post type called "wines", and then it has attributes as vintage, grape color..... and also, "region" and "producer". I have created those two last ones as custom post types because the user needs to be able to create a "producer" and "region" page/post through the dashboard, basically, they want the same elements than when you create a new post.

I am not allow to work with any plugin (paid or not) or any theme, so I have to hard code everything.

The fact is.... I have tried to create them as taxonomies, but then I couldn't work out how to add all the functionality a post or a page has trough the dashboard, as it only comes with title, slug, and description...

Well, now my problem is, I have created meta boxes with dropdowns, so when you are creating a new wine, you select the region and the producer in the meta box. Problem? it just save the producer :S as soon as I select the region, and I try to update, the selected option becomes unselected again.

Any suggestion about why is it happening? And in case there is something going on with wp_dropdown_pages, as it is the only thing makes me thing it can be wrong.... any other solution suggested?

Thank you!!

So here I register my custom post-types:

```
add_action('init', function(){
    $labels = array(
        "name" => "Producers",
        "singular_name" => "Producer",
        "menu_name" => "Producers",
        "all_items" => "All Producers",
        "add_new" => "Add New",
        "add_new_item" => "Add New Producers",
        "edit" => "Edit",
        "edit_item" => "Edit Producer",
        "new_item" => "New Producer",
        "view" => "View",
        "view_item" => "View Producer",
        "search_items" => "Search Producers",
        "not_found" => "No Producers Found",
        "not_found_in_trash" => "No Producers Found in Trash",
        "parent" => "Parent Producers",
    );

    $args = array(
        "labels" => $labels,
         "description" => "",
        "public" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "has_archive" => true,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "exclude_from_search" => false,
        "capability_type" => "post",
        "map_meta_cap" => true,
        "hierarchical" => true,
        "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "producers", "with_front" => true ),
        "query_var" => true,
        "supports" => array(
           "editor",
            "title",
            "thumbnail",
            "revisions",
            "custom-fields",
            "page-attributes",   
        )
    );

    register_post_type( "producer", $args );

    $labels = array(
        "name" => "Wines",
        "singular_name" => "Wine",
    );

    $args = array(
        "labels" => $labels,
        "description" => "",
        "public" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "has_archive" => true,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "exclude_from_search" => false,
        "capability_type" => "post",
        "map_meta_cap" => true,
        "hierarchical" => false,
        "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "wines", "with_front" => true ),
        "query_var" => true,
        "supports" => array(  
            "editor",
            "title",
            "thumbnail",
            "revisions",
            "custom-fields",
            "page-attributes",
        ), 
    );

    register_post_type( "wines", $args );

       $labels = array(
        "name" => "Regions",
        "singular_name" => "Region",
        "menu_name" => "Regions",
        "all_items" => "All Regions",
        "add_new" => "Add New",
        "add_new_item" => "Add Region",
        "edit" => "Edit",
        "edit_item" => "Edit Region",
        "new_item" => "Region",
        "view" => "View",
        "view_item" => "View Region",
        "search_items" => "Search Regions",
        "not_found" => "No Region Found",
        "not_found_in_trash" => "No Region Found in Trash",
        "parent" => "Parent Country",
    );

    $args = array(
        "labels" => $labels,
         "description" => "",
        "public" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "has_archive" => true,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "exclude_from_search" => false,
        "capability_type" => "post",
        "map_meta_cap" => true,
        "hierarchical" => true,
        "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "regions", "with_front" => true ),
        "query_var" => true,
        "supports" => array(
           "editor",
            "title",
            "thumbnail",
            "revisions",
            "custom-fields",
            "page-attributes",   
        )
    );

    register_post_type( "region", $args );
});
```

Here I register the metaboxes with the dropdowns:

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', function() {
    add_meta_box('wines2-parent', 'regions', 'wines_attributes_meta_box2', 'wines', 'side', 'default');
});

function wines_attributes_meta_box2($post) {
        $pages = wp_dropdown_pages(array('post_type' => 'region', 'selected' => $post->post_parent, 'name' => 'parent_id', 'show_option_none' => __('(no parent)'), 'sort_column'=> 'menu_order, post_title', 'echo' => 0));
        if ( ! empty($pages) ) {
            echo $pages;
        } // end empty pages check
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', function() {
    add_meta_box('wines-parent', 'producers', 'wines_attributes_meta_box', 'wines', 'side', 'default');
});

function wines_attributes_meta_box($post) {
        $pages = wp_dropdown_pages(array('post_type' => 'producer', 'selected' => $post->post_parent, 'name' => 'parent_id', 'show_option_none' => __('(no parent)'), 'sort_column'=> 'menu_order, post_title', 'echo' => 0));
        if ( ! empty($pages) ) {
            echo $pages;
        } // end empty pages check
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Problem? it just save the producer :S as soon as I select the region,
>   and I try to update, the selected option becomes unselected again.

The underlying problem seems to be that you're adding two select boxes on the edit page with the **same name attribute**, namely `parent_id`.

Note that this is also the same name attribute used by the default parent select box in the *Page Attribute* meta-box.

The `parent_id` is stored in the `wp_posts` table and that field is `unsigned` `bigint(20)`. So this can only store a single integer.

You should use two different name attributes, like:

```
wp_dropdown_pages( [ 'name' => 'wpse_producer_id', ...

wp_dropdown_pages( [ 'name' => 'wpse_region_id', ...
```

where we prefixed it, with `wpse_` as an example, to avoid possible name collisions.

Then you could store these values as post meta, for each post, with the help of `update_post_meta()`. There are some examples [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/) in the Codex.

You would also have to adjust the selected attribute with the help of `get_post_meta()`.

Hope it helps.